# jQuery .animate({left}) not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I made a quick jQuery piece using `.animate()` and it works perfectly in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but when I open it in IE the beginning animation starts and then jumps directly to where then.fadeOut portion begins. Any ideas how I can change this to work in IE?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

//ACC LOGO COMES IN
$("#img1").animate({left:'+=470'},1000);
$("#img1").animate("pause");
$("#img1").animate("pause");
$("#img1").animate("pause");
//AVERY LOGO COMES IN
$("#img1").animate({left:'+=470'},1000);
$("#img1").animate("pause");
$("#img1").animate("pause");
$("#img1").animate("pause");
$("#img1").animate({left:'+=470'},1000);

//FADE OUT RED FADE INTO COLOR PHOTO
$("#img1").fadeOut("fast", function(){
    $("#img0").fadeOut(2000, function(){
        $("#img3").fadeOut(3000, function(){
            $("#img4").fadeOut(2000, function(){
                $("#img5").fadeOut(3000);
                });
            });
        });
//END OF FADE QUEUE
});

//END DOC READY BRACKET
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="img1"><img src="images/slide_double.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="img0"><img src="images/slide_0.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="img3"><img src="images/slide_3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="img4"><img src="images/slide_4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="img5"><img src="images/slide_5.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="img6"><img src="images/slide_6.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow {
background-image:url('images/slide_0.jpg');
height: 270px;
width: 460px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#img1 {
height: 270px;
width: 460px;
position: relative;
left: -940px;
} 

#img0 {
height: 270px;
width: 460px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 6;
}   

#img3 {
height: 270px;
width: 460px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5
}

#img3 {
    height: 270px;
width: 460px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 4
}

#img4 {
height: 270px;
width: 460px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3
}

#img5 {
height: 270px;
width: 460px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2
}

#img6 {
height: 270px;
width: 460px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1
}
```

Comment: `.animate("pause")`!? Also, when it comes down to IE you need to be more specific about which version it is

Comment: Honestly, I'm new to jQuery... is there something wrong with using `.animate("pause")`? Also, I'm using IE 8

Comment: As far as I know that is not stock jQuery

Comment: You can use .delay() function instead of .animate("pause")

Comment: @sdespont - post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no `pause` option working with the `animate` JQuery function

To simulate a pause, you can use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) JQuery function.

**Updated**

http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/2/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#img1").animate({
         left: '+=470px' //ACC LOGO COMES IN 
     }, 1000).delay(1500).animate({
         left: '+=470'   //AVERY LOGO COMES IN
     }, 1000).delay(1500).animate({
         left: '+=470'
     }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: I changed the function to `.delay(1500)` (thank you!) but again it works well in everything except IE

Comment: Seems like it ended up being a syntax error after I changed it to .delay from .animate("pause"), because this works in IE for me now:

    $(document).ready(function(){  

     //ACC LOGO COMES IN
    $("#img1").animate({ left: '+=470px' }, 1000).delay(1500);

    //AVERY LOGO COMES IN
$("#img1").animate({ left: '+=470' }, 1000).delay(1500);

$("#img1").animate({ left: '+=470' }, 1000);

Comment: I have updated my answe with a tested fiddle in IE. You can also use JQuery chaining instead of declare your image every times